# Splitting large data frame by column into smaller data frames (not lists) using loops

Tags: r, loops, split

I have many large data frames. Using of the smaller ones for example:

```
dim(ch29)  
476 4283
```

I need to split it into smaller pieces (i.e. subset into 241 columns at the most). My problems come afterwards when I want to analyze these smaller subsets.

I do not know how to subset the ***large date-frame*** into ***smaller data-frames*** and ***not simply a list***.

I also want to do all of this in a loop and give the newly created smaller data frames unique names in the loop.

```
chunk=241
df<-ch29
n<-ceiling(ncol(df)/chunk)

for (i in 1:n) {
  xname <- paste("ch29", i, sep="_")
  cat("_", xname)
  assign(xname, split(df, rep(1:n, each=chunk, length.out=ncol(df))))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for (i in 1:3) { # i = 1
  xname = paste("ch29", i, sep = "_")
  col.min = (i - 1) * chunk + 1
  col.max = min(i * chunk, ncol(df))
  assign(xname, df[,col.min:col.max])
}
```

In other words, use the notation `df[,a:b]`, where `a < b`, to get the subset of the dataframe `df` consisting only of columns `a` to `b`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do or how you want to choose the columns that go in each data frame, but here's an example of one option:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(100)
ch29 = as.data.frame(replicate(4283, rnorm(476)))

# Number of columns we want in each split data frame
ncols = floor(ncol(ch29)/20)

# Start column for each split data frame
start = seq(1,ncol(ch29),ncols)

# Split ch29 into a bunch of separate data frames
df.list = lapply(setNames(start, paste0("ch29_", start, "_", start+ncols-1)), 
                 function(i) ch29[ , i:min(i+ncols-1,ncol(ch29))])
```

You now have a list, `df.list`, where each list element is a data frame with `ncols` columns from `ch29`, except for the last element of the list, which will have between 1 and `ncols` columns. Also, the name of each list element is the name of the parent data frame (`ch29`) and the column range from which the subset data frame is drawn.